# How to follow the DRY principle in Django CBV when each view is dealing with same model but returns different data based on filter conditions?

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, dry, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

I have several pages that renders different data from a same model, I am using generic CBV to list data on page, logic for each view is same but it renders different data based on filter conditions provided, I don't see any way to cut down on repeating code on this as the different views all have to deal with a same model.

`views.py`

```
class AcceptedBlockView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'blocks/blockslist.html'
    model = Block
    page = 'acceptedblock'
    extra_context = {'page' : page}

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Block.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, status = 'Accepted')
        return queryset


class CompletedBlockView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'blocks/blockslist.html'
    model = Block
    page = 'completedblock'
    extra_context = {'page' : page}

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Block.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, status = 'Completed')
        return queryset
```

HTML code for the same is `blockslist.html`

```
{% if page == 'completedblock' %}
<h2>Completed Blocks</h2>
<table>
    <thead class="thed-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Update Block</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for instance in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
            <td>{{ instance.title }}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'updateblock' instance.id %}">Update</a></td>
            <td>{{ instance.status }}</td>
            <td>{{ instance.user }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<p>Click here to see <a href="{% url 'allblocks' %}">All Your Blocks</a></p>
<p>Click here to see <a href="{% url 'acceptedblock' %}">Accepted Blocks</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: If this code works, but you need help improving it, it's better suited for the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
# remove get_queryset method and implement this method in your CBV
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['b1'] = Block.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, status='Accepted')
    context['b2'] = Block.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, status='Completed')
    return context
```